# need performance to use aggregate N1QL

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I have a query like below

```
select sum(ARRAY_SUM(DailyCampaignUsage.`data`[*].cost)) revenue from 
Inheritx DailyCampaignUsage   WHERE DailyCampaignUsage._type='DailyCampaignUsage'
```

it is taking **12.3s**

here **count(ARRAY_SUM(DailyCampaignUsage.`data`[*].cost))** it is **51k**

How I can improve it's performance ??
I have index like below

```
CREATE INDEX `abc` ON `Inheritx`(`_type`) USING GSI
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a covering partial index.

```
CREATE INDEX idx_covering ON Inheritx(_type, data[*].cost) WHERE _type = 'DailyCampaignUsage';

select sum(ARRAY_SUM(DailyCampaignUsage.`data`[*].cost)) revenue
from Inheritx DailyCampaignUsage USE INDEX ( idx_covering )
WHERE DailyCampaignUsage._type='DailyCampaignUsage'
```

Comment: thanks it taking now 1s
But how can I improve its performance




ROUND(sum(CASe WHEN  DailyCampaignUsage.day between '2016-12-01' and '2016-12-05' THEN ARRAY_SUM(DailyCampaignUsage.`data`[*].cost) ELSE 0 END)